# Deploy Python-Flask api in Azure

Tags: python-3.x, azure

I have deployed Python-Flask API in Azure. Its working fine in development environment. It has following dependencies which is mentioned in a .txt file.

- click==6.7
- Flask==1.0.2
- itsdangerous==0.24
- Jinja2==2.10
- MarkupSafe==1.0
- Werkzeug==0.14.1
- jsonpickle==1.0
- pyodbc==4.0.25

I have an **app.py** class which has some function that contains some **DB CURD** operations. It also has a **db.py** which contain below code :

`import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cs)`

But when I am navigating to https://kmsazapi.azurewebsites.net/ it is giving below error
**:( Application Error.** *If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.*

**Please find the Application logs from Azure :**

2019-01-19T16:30:46.743756546Z 
2019-01-19T16:30:46.893500456Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2019-01-19T16:30:46.921319668Z Running python /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.py
2019-01-19T16:30:47.042444539Z executing:
2019-01-19T16:30:47.042628845Z python --version
2019-01-19T16:30:47.060630336Z Python 3.7.1
2019-01-19T16:30:47.060830442Z executing:
2019-01-19T16:30:47.060993448Z pip --version
2019-01-19T16:30:49.209547693Z pip 10.0.1 from /home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
2019-01-19T16:30:49.214266747Z found flask app
2019-01-19T16:30:49.219978635Z executing:
2019-01-19T16:30:49.219990835Z . antenv/bin/activate
2019-01-19T16:30:49.224706090Z 
2019-01-19T16:30:49.224798193Z executing:
2019-01-19T16:30:49.224971698Z GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600" gunicorn application:app
2019-01-19T16:30:50.183264018Z [2019-01-19 16:30:50 +0000] [36] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-01-19T16:30:50.183984042Z [2019-01-19 16:30:50 +0000] [36] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (36)
2019-01-19T16:30:50.184216749Z [2019-01-19 16:30:50 +0000] [36] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-01-19T16:30:50.194083973Z [2019-01-19 16:30:50 +0000] [39] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 39

**2019-01-19T16:30:50.967282324Z [2019-01-19 16:30:50 +0000] [39] [ERROR] Exception in worker process**

2019-01-19T16:30:50.967302024Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967306124Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967311525Z     worker.init_process()
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967325625Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967329625Z     self.load_wsgi()
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967332825Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967336425Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967347026Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967350926Z     self.callable = self.load()
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967354226Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967357626Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967361026Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967364426Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967367726Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967371427Z     **import**(module)
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967374727Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/application.py", line 7, in 
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967378427Z     import db
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967381627Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/db.py", line 1, in 
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967385027Z     import pyodbc
**2019-01-19T16:30:50.967388327Z ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
2019-01-19T16:30:50.967653236Z [2019-01-19 16:30:50 +0000] [39] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 39)
2019-01-19T16:30:51.050986468Z [2019-01-19 16:30:51 +0000] [36] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
**2019-01-19T16:30:51.051229076Z [2019-01-19 16:30:51 +0000] [36] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.**
2019-01-19T16:30:51.102156846Z

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: 0115:**

If you deploy the python app to web app for windows, you can install the python extension as below:  Go to azure portal -> your app service -> Extensions -> Add -> choose extensions:

[image]

[image]

---

How do you deploy your flask app?

You can refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python#prerequisites) for the deployment. I followed the doc, and can work well in azure with the site `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/home` .

my code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return "Hello World a nice day!"
```

after deploy to azure, the site works well:

[image]

Comment: Ivan, in local development environment my API is working fine but after deployment in Azure, it is not working. As i mentioned in the post that in Azure portal I am only getting two version of Python i.e 2.7 and 3.4 and i have selected 3.4 version of it.   My be due to version mismatch it is giving this error.  Is there any way i can add more versions of Python in Azure portal ?

Comment: @semwal Can you give it a try by following the doc I mentioned in my post? For python version, I check it by using this cli command **az webapp list-runtimes --linux**, and the result is that no 3.4, but have 2.7,3.6,3.7.

Comment: @semwal, if you deploy the python app to **app service for windows**, you can refer to my updated section in my answer. Please let me know if any questions.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I have used official doc and it worked.

Comment: I have updated the issue with Azure Application logs. Thanks !!